# Mock lodash _orderBy method with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm wondering how I can mock a lodash _orderBy method with Jest and make sure that it has been called with the arguments as below.

**My Vue.component method sliceArray**

```
 sliceArray: function(array) {
          let val = _.orderBy(array, "orderDate", "desc");
          return val.slice(0, this.numberOfErrandsLoaded);
        }
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import _ from "lodash";
jest.unmock("lodash");

it("Check orderBy method from lodash", () => {
    _.orderBy = jest.fn();
    expect(_.orderBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([], "orderDate", "desc");
  });
```

The current error message:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: [], "orderDate", "desc"

Number of calls: 0
```

Thanks beforehand!

/ E

Comment: try mocking `lodash/orderBy.js` instead of `_.orderBy = jest.fn()`. At the time when you rewrite it directly, your component has been imported lodash and executed with original version.

Comment: btw do you _really_ need validating that? what if you just validate rendering outcomes instead?

Answer (score 1):

This what I do test imported libraries. I use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
const spyOrderByLodash = jest.spyOn(_, 'orderBy');

it("Check orderBy method from lodash", () => {
    expect(spyOrderByLodash).toHaveBeenCalledWith([], "orderDate", "desc");
  });
```

Don't forget to clearAllMocks before each test (optional but a must if you have multiple tests in a single file):

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
```

Comment: Interesting. I still seem to get the same error message as before I'm afraid!

Comment: probably because of extra space in `spyOn`: `orderBy `

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Melchia's solution:

```
import lodash from "lodash";
const spyOrderByLodash = jest.spyOn(_, 'orderBy');

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

it("Check orderBy method from lodash", () => {
    expect(spyOrderByLodash).toHaveBeenCalledWith([], "orderDate", "desc");
  });
```